# Run a maven plugin from a jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a project built spring boot (a recent version), java 17.
It uses flyway for running migrations.

For example, `mvn flyway:migrate` works well when I have access to the source code.

Though, I created an uber-jar which does contain the migration files. Maven is not installed on the target server and I do not have access to the source repository.

Is there a way to a execute a maven plugin (eg. `flyway:migrate`), when I only have access to the JAR?